# Removing an ID from a NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to calculate the total charged on a per client basis, where a client has a registered property in one table, where they have not been invoiced in another, but I am not sure how to write the 'Not In' portion of the query so that it does not have to reference a specific ID.

The query listed below is part of a larger query to calculate overall totals, but I am struggling with this particular piece.

I have tried to modify the 'Not In' portion of the query to remove the reference to a specific ID and do a Group By the client_id, but this did not return any results. I also tried a GROUP_CONCAT, but I'm not sure I implemented that properly.

I'm not sure if a) what I'm trying to do is possible, or b) if there's a much better way to go about doing what I'm trying to accomplish, but I feel like if I could write this in another subquery, I'd be in much better shape, but I can't wrap my head around how to write it or even another way to approach the problem.

```
SELECT 
    clients.client_id,
    clients.first_name,
    clients.last_name,
    SUM(total_charged) AS total_charged
FROM
    clients
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT 
                clients.client_id,
                route_property_reg.route_property_reg_id,
                route_property_reg.rate_charged AS total_charged
            FROM
                clients
                LEFT JOIN properties ON clients.client_id = properties.client_id
                LEFT JOIN route_property_reg ON properties.property_id = route_property_reg.property_id
            WHERE
                route_property_reg.route_property_reg_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        invoice_lines.route_property_reg_id
                    FROM
                        clients
                        LEFT JOIN invoices ON clients.client_id = invoices.client_id
                        LEFT JOIN invoice_lines ON invoices.invoice_id = invoice_lines.invoice_id
                    WHERE
                        clients.client_id = 1)
             GROUP BY clients.client_id) 
             AS charged ON clients.client_id = charged.client_id
             GROUP BY clients.client_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737bba/1/0)

An alternative Fiddle with another attempt but similar results: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737bba/2/0)

Expected/Anticipated Output would be:

```
| client_id | first_name | last_name | total_charged |
|-----------|------------|-----------|---------------|
|         1 |       John |       Doe |           200 |  - (route-properties # 1 and 4)
|         2 |       Jane |       Doe |           200 |  - (route-property #5)
|         3 |       John |     Smith |        (null) |
|         4 |       Jane |     Smith |        (null) |
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: A general "A not in B" pattern is `SELECT ... FROM clients LEFT JOIN invoices ON ... WHERE invoices.id IS NULL`

Comment: Instead of us trying to crystal ball, why not just supply a more **sample data** (covering every table needed) and then the **expected result** of that data?

Comment: Original question has been updated with a simplified query and a link to the SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of guess and check, the following works for me:

```
SELECT 
    clients.client_id,
        clients.first_name,
        COALESCE(SUM(total_charged), 0) AS total_charged
FROM
    clients
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    c.client_id,
        a.route_property_reg_id,
        COALESCE(SUM(ROUND((a.rate_charged * (1 + (tax_types.rate / 100))), 2)), 0) AS total_charged
FROM
    route_property_reg a
LEFT JOIN properties ON a.property_id = properties.property_id
LEFT JOIN clients c ON properties.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN tax_types ON a.tax_rate_charged = tax_types.tax_type_id
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            NULL
        FROM
            invoice_lines b
        LEFT JOIN invoices ON b.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN clients d ON invoices.client_id = d.client_id
        WHERE
            b.route_property_reg_id = a.route_property_reg_id
                AND d.client_id = c.client_id)
GROUP BY client_id) AS charged ON clients.client_id = charged.client_id
GROUP BY clients.client_id
```